# I want to know about usage of 'make fun'

Tags: verbs

Here I want to mean that-- I enjoy(without mocking anyone).
Q.Then are these sentences correct?

1. I make fun.
2. I do fun.
3. I make it fun.

Q.Everywhere I see 'make fun of'. Can't I use 'make fun' without the preposition 'of'?

Comment: There's a major difference in the meaning of "make fun of" vs "make it fun".

Comment: Please explain it, sir

Comment: Using "make fun" in a non-derisive sense is fairly rare and requires some skill.

Comment: Which of my sentences correct, please tell me..

Comment: _Have_ is the usual delexical verb: _They had fun in the sun_. 'Make merry' is an old-fashioned expression that stands alone. 'They make it fun to learn' (with non/quasi-referential _it_)  is a typical way of using 'make' and 'fun' in closish proximity.

Comment: Then can i say  "we have fun on Sundays" in place of  "we enjoy Sundays"? Or i can say "we name fun on Sundays"?

Comment: Yes - _have fun_, but not _do fun_ or _name fun_.

Comment: And " I make it fun on Sundays " -is it correct?

Comment: [Shades of Fleetwood Mac](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=you+make+loving+fun+song), and Chrissie McVie

Comment: @user386586 - To make it fun is to take a task that is not considered to be enjoyable and put it in a new context so that one now wants to do it.  To make a game of it.   Ask Mary Poppins for help on how to do that.